# oracle<sid> (LOCAL=NO)

Tags: oracle

yesterday we restarted our database on production and after that we started listen post one hour. We saw later in the night that server was flooded with oracle (LOCAL=NO) and stopped accepting request for new connections. 
Later we killed the processes and system was back to normal.

any idea what could have been caused these defunct processes.

I looked into sqlnet logs and I found this..

```
Fatal NI connect error 12537, connecting to:
 (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=100.20.1.1.)(PORT=1522))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=xyz)(CID=(PROGRAM=emagent)(HOST=abc.com)(USER=oracle))))

  VERSION INFORMATION:
        TNS for Solaris: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
        TCP/IP NT Protocol Adapter for Solaris: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
  Time: 23-AUG-2014 10:19:01
  Tracing not turned on.
  Tns error struct:
    ns main err code: 12537
    TNS-12537: TNS:connection closed
    ns secondary err code: 12560
    nt main err code: 507
    TNS-00507: Connection closed
```

...

```
Fatal NI connect error 12541, connecting to:
 (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=100.20.1.1.)(PORT=1522))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=xyz)(CID=(PROGRAM=emagent)(HOST=abc.com)(USER=oracle))))

  VERSION INFORMATION:
        TNS for Solaris: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
        TCP/IP NT Protocol Adapter for Solaris: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
  Time: 22-AUG-2014 15:37:26
  Tracing not turned on.
  Tns error struct:
    ns main err code: 12541
    TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
    ns secondary err code: 12560
    nt main err code: 511
    TNS-00511: No listener
    nt secondary err code: 146
    nt OS err code: 0
```

and the entire sqlnet.log file was als flooded with such messages. When we killed the defunct processes, sqlnet.log file also got stopped updated.

Comment: This is a guess - you had processes connect from apps like backup software( Tivoli, CommVault, RMAN).  The apps had problems and bailed leaving disconnected processes.

Answer (score 1):

The part that says `PROGRAM=emagent` suggests that your issue was related to Oracle Enterprise Manager Grid Control Agent.  Did you have issues with the Oracle Agent at that time?  Check your Agent with `emctl status agent` (after setting agent environment).  The agent also has some log and trc files you could check.

- If you connect from a different host (via SQL*Net), you will certainly see `LOCAL=NO` on the process.
- If you see `LOCAL=YES`, then the process was created by a local connection from the same server using (i.e. Bequeath), bypassing SQL*Net.  This happens when you do `sqlplus / as sysdba`.
- If you see `LOCAL=NO`, the session may or may not have originated from a different host. For example, you could connect from the same host, but explicitly using SQL*Net.  An EM agent running on the same host as the database typically connects as `LOCAL=NO` (at least the EM agents in my Oracle environment work that way).